# Running a statistical test column wise in a multi-column csv file in python

Tags: python

I want to run t-test while comparing first two columns of a dataframe with the third column and then move on and compare fourth and fifth column with the sixth column and so on. My csv file has 216 columns.
I know how to run test on two columns.

```
a = column1, c = column3
stats.ttest_rel(a,c)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the following (`df` being a placeholder for your dataframe):

```
i=0
while i < len(df.columns):
    stats.ttest_rel(df.iloc[:,i],df.iloc[:,i+2])
    stats.ttest_rel(df.iloc[:,i+1],df.iloc[:,i+2])
    i += 3
```

---

Edit: The following adjustment handles potential errors, in case there is something wrong with your dataframe, you are unsure about its properties or other eventualities occur.

```
i=0
while i >=0:
    try:
        stats.ttest_rel(df.iloc[:,i],df.iloc[:,i+2])
        stats.ttest_rel(df.iloc[:,i+1],df.iloc[:,i+2])
        i += 3
    except:
        break
```

Comment: This is throwing KeyError: 0

Comment: @AsifMarazi Sorry, I assumed that the columns of your dataframe were named by their respective indices - you received the error since this is not the case. I have now updated my code suggestion to account for this. Let me know whether it works for you.

Comment: Thanks, but now it shows IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds

Comment: I just run my snippet with a dummy dataframe of 216 columns and it worked fine. Are you sure that your dataframe has 216 columns? The error suggests that the index was out of bounds, however this should not be a case for 216 columns (instead it should run smoothly for 72 iterations and when break out of the loop). It is difficult to tell you more since you have not provided details of your dataframe, but what you could do is add `try` and `except` to the loop so that it breaks out of the loop when the acceptable indices have been exceeded. For this, see the edit in my answer.

Comment: This code does exactly what I want. Thank you so much.